# DatePicker - how to keep the selected value after clicking on submit button

Tags: java, javascript, liferay, liferay-6

I want to keep the selected value after clicking on submit button.
Right now when i chhose value from datepicker and when i click on submit button then my textbox value become empty. I used javascript.Following is my code

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

});
</script>


<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="<portlet:namespace/>datepicker"  value=""/><br>
```

How can i solve this problem please help me...
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you set `value=""`, you should expect to get the default, whatever datepicker displays. Set it to the value that you want to start with and you should be good.

Figure out the formatting that it requires, most likely it's the same one that gets transmitted as request parameter when you submit your form.

Comment: can you please help . How can i set that value? Once i select any date and press submit button then my textbox became empty.What i have to set in vale so I i didn't lost my value

Comment: it's impossible to give you the exact code, as I don't know what your portlet and request handling looks like. You'll have to identify if you get hold of the originally submitted value and use something like `value="<%=whateverValueYouWantToSet %>"`